# Loading Selenium user profile in Tor Chrome on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

This code works for Windows where it launches Chrome connected via Tor. Keep in mind you have to have Tor browser running *beforehand*. How can I enable the user-profile and start the browser logged in? I have tried the regular method. I have only 1 profile. Default. Doesn't seem to be working. Any clues?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


tor_proxy = "127.0.0.1:9150"

chrome_options = Options()

'''chrome_options.add_argument("--test-type")'''
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
'''chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')'''
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
'''chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")'''
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default')
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=socks5://%s' % tor_proxy)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.gmail.com')
time.sleep(4)
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_id("introAgreeButton").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead.

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
```

you don't have to specify the profile directory (Default) as it is used by default if nothing is explicitly specified using below code. SO in your case use only the above line of code

```
chrome_options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
```

Eg:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   
options = Options()
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\prave\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
    
driver =webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver.exe",options=options)

driver.get(url)
```

**Output:**

[image]